# sencha touch select field change event not firing if store has duplicate names

Tags: sencha-touch-2

sencha touch select field change event not firing if store has duplicate names

suppose my data looks like

options: [{
                        text: 'Sencha Touch',
                        value: 'extjs'
                    }, {
                        text: 'Sencha Touch',
                        value: 'senchatouch'
                    }, {
                        text: 'Sencha Animator',
                        value: 'animator'
                    }, {
                        text: 'Sencha Designer',
                        value: 'designer'
                    }], // options
for the above code the change event not fired for same text

help me?

Answer (score 0):

change event only fires when the new value is actually different from the old value. Not just for select fields, but for all field.